# Karaf and java_home

Tags: java, apache-karaf

Is there a way to set the default java path for karaf without using the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

E.g. one of the settings files?

I have another application that requires the JAVA_HOME variable set to a diffrent version of jre and can't repoint the path for this.

Karaf is currently being run as a Windows service and the console is accessed via client.bat

Comment: Are you launching Karaf from a terminal? Tell us more about your work environent

Comment: @codigocaballer karaf is installed as a windows service and run via client.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you are are running `karaf` as `Windows service`, so I guess you are using [Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/home.html)
In the Wrapper configuration file change the default JRE/JDK path and restart your `karaf` application.

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************
set.default.JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\
```